# Auto increment name field and check how many auto increment variables are sent with serialize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I have a button that the user presses to add more inputs. The reasoning behind this is to add additional 'guests'. The functionality of adding the inputs works fine. The part I can't figure out is how to auto increment the JS so that each new input adds an auto increment count to the `name="guest"`.

I am serializing the data and sending it via AJAX to a php file. Is there also a way to program the variables, so it checks how many `guests` are being sent over, so I don't have guest1, guest2, guest3, etc. If I do this, there may be variables undefined.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
document.getElementById('guestWrap').innerHTML += '<div class="formField" id="guestName"><label class="label">What is your guest\'s name?</label><input type="text" class="input" name="guest" id="guest"></div>';
```

PHP

```
$guest1 = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['guest1'], ENT_QUOTES));
$guest2 = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['guest'], ENT_QUOTES));
$guest3 = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['guest'], ENT_QUOTES));
```

JS

```
$('#addGuest').click(function() {
    document.getElementById('guestWrap').innerHTML += '<div class="formField" id="guestName"><label class="label">What is your guest\'s name?</label><input type="text" class="input" name="guest" id="guest"></div>';
});
```

HTML - The first guest field, labeled as guest1

```
<div class="formField guestName" id="guestName">
    <label class="label">What is your guest's name?</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="guest1" id="guest1">
</div>
```

[image]

AJAX:

```
$('#rsvpForm').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "Please enter your name",
            minlength: "Your name seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
        },
        email: {
            required: "Please enter your email address",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
       event.preventDefault();
        var datastring1 = $('#rsvpForm').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'rsvpSend.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: datastring1
            ,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 'Error!') {
                    alert('Unable to  submit RSVP!');
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                /*  $('#application-form')[0].reset();
                    $('#application-form').slideUp(400);
                    $('#tell-us-title').fadeOut(200);
                    $('#make-it-count').fadeOut(200);
                    $('#inquiry-success').fadeIn(200);*/
                }
            },
            complete:function(){
                //$('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('#inquiry-success').offset().top -25}, 'slow');
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + '|' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Full HTML

```
<form id="rsvpForm">
            <div class="formField">
                <label class="label"><span class="red"> *</span></label>
                <input type="radio" value="Yes" class="radio" name="yesno" id="yes">
                <label class="radioAnswer" for="yes">Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" value="No" class="radio" name="yesno" id="no">
                <label class="radioAnswer" for="no">NO</label>
            </div>
            <div class="formField" id="ansYes">
                <label class="label">Will you be bringing any guests?</label>
                <input type="radio" value="Yes" class="radio" name="yesno2" id="yes2">
                <label class="radioAnswer" for="yes2">Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" value="No" class="radio" name="yesno2" id="no2">
                <label class="radioAnswer" for="no2">NO</label>
            </div>
            <div id="guestWrap">
                <div class="formField guestName" id="guestName">
                    <label class="label">What is your guest's name?</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input" name="guest1" id="guest1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="addGuest">
                <span class="guestIncrease">Add another guest</span>
            </div>
            <div class="formField">
                <label class="label">What is your name?<span class="red"> *</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="input">
            </div>
            <div class="formField">
                <label class="label">What is your email?<span class="red"> *</span></label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="input">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" id="submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: Do you also have a remove guest button?

Comment: @31piy No, I don't. It really isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a Remove guest button, then it is pretty straight forward.

On click of the add guest button, get the count of existing guests. Create the new guest element with the ID as count + 1.

```
$('#addGuest').click(function() {
    var count = $('.formField.guestName').length;
    document.getElementById('guestWrap').innerHTML += '<div class="formField guestName" id="guestName' + (count + 1) + '"><label class="label">What is your guest\'s name?</label><input type="text" class="input" name="guest' + (count + 1) + '" id="guest' + (count + 1) + '"></div>';
});
```

Please note that all the guest `div`s must have class `formField` and `guestName` assigned for this code to work correctly. If you've any other criteria, you should modify the selector to get the count.

Comment: I tried what you put, but it doesn't work. In my network console, the only input field that is showing numbered is the one I hard coded into the html. I tried changing your count variable to : `var count = $('#guestName').length;` but no luck.

Comment: @Paul -- can you show me how do you send the data to the server? Is there an AJAX call, or you just submit the form? Please update your question with these details.

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot of the network tab.

Comment: Ajax has been added.

Comment: Just added to the question.

Comment: @Paul -- can you see the the correct HTML using browser's inspection tools when you add a new guest to the list? Can you verify if the name is being assigned properly?

Comment: It appears that my "Add a guest" function stopped working. The inputs do not add anymore. There isn't any errors in the console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169485/discussion-between-31piy-and-paul).